# Fragment android, does not execute the method oncreateview

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I contact you because I am the 10 days I have this problem:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out); 
ft.add(R.id.fragmentdx, fragment2, "esss");
ft.commit();
```

If I try to use this code, is not no problem, after performing ft.commit within the method "Oncreateview"

---

But if I try to add this code after a ft.commit

```
FragmentDx centralFragment=(dx) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentdx)
centralFragment.showCityDetails(cityName);
```

I will not go more in the method "Oncreateview"

why? What's wrong?

How can I recover the fragment given ID?

thank you very much, Sorry for my english

Comment: May we see your `onCreateView` method?

Comment: onCreateView only gets called when the fragment is first created not when you try to get an instance of the fragment

Comment: if you post your oncreateview code it would helpful..

Comment: It's logical that onCreateView is not called. Your fragment wasn't recreated.. Why would you think that findFragmentById would trigger a recreation of the fragment?